# How can I convert dictionary entries from String to timestamp in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have a dictionary with two dates:

```
dateFilter = {"date1": "2021-05-14", "date2": "2021-05-10"}
```

In my dataframe I have two columns of type timestamp:

```
|date1 | date2|
———————————————
|timea | timeb|
|timec | timed|
```

I want to filter this table based on whether the entries are smaller than the time in the dictionary

```
Table = Table.filter(F.col(column) <= DateFilters[date1])
```

The column needs to stay type timestamp so in order to compare I would like to convert the dictionary entries from String to Timestamp. I've tried this:

```
DateFilters[date1] = DateFilters[date1].cast(T.TimestampType)
```

But this doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a literal timestamp column from the dictionary value:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Table = Table.filter(F.col(column) <= F.lit(DateFilters["date1"]).cast('timestamp'))
```